# How to run find query for a range on a selected field

Tags: java, database, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to run the following using mongo java driver

```
db.collection.find({"Date": 20171108}, {_id : false})
```

However I am trying to stretch this over multiple dates. Such as 10/30/2017 - 11/8/2017. To do this I am setting up the following

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject startDate = new BasicDBObject("Date", "20171030");
BasicDBObject endDate = new BasicDBObject("Date", "20171108");
```

but I am unsure of how to combine them both together to do something like

```
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query, <startDate endDate>);
```

I'm new to mongo so any help is appricated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the below criteria:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String startDateString = "20171030";
    String endDateString = "20171108";
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;

    try {
        startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
        endDate = df.parse(endDateString);
        BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject();
        criteria.put("Date", new BasicDBObject(new BasicDBObject("$gte", startDate).append("$lte", endDate)));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and then:

```
db.find(criteria);
```

Comment: And would this cover all the dates between the start and end dates?

Comment: Yes, it returns all the entries where the field Dates is less than or equal to endDate ($lte)  and greater than or equal to ($gte) startDate. If you want to compare only less and greater values but not equals, you can use the operators $lt and $gt. You can find all the operation in the following link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/